# How to find top three highest salary in emp table in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

How to find top three highest salary in `emp` table in oracle?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
SELECT  *FROM 
    (
    SELECT *FROM emp 
    ORDER BY Salary desc
    )
WHERE rownum <= 3
ORDER BY Salary ;
```

Comment: why the ORDER BY Salary required after WHERE??

Comment: because the salaries will list in descending order without it

Answer (score 14):

You can try.

```
   SELECT * FROM 
     (
      SELECT EMPLOYEE, LAST_NAME, SALARY,
      RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SALARY DESC) EMPRANK
      FROM emp
     )
    WHERE emprank <= 3;
```

This will give correct output even if there are two employees with same maximun  salary

Answer (score 4):

Something like the following should do it.

```
SELECT  Name, Salary
FROM 
    (
    SELECT  Name, Salary
    FROM         emp 
    ORDER BY Salary desc
    )
WHERE rownum <= 3
ORDER BY Salary ;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT a.ename, b.sal
    FROM emp a, emp b
    WHERE a.empno = b.empno
          AND
          3 > (SELECT count(*) FROM emp b
                   WHERE a.sal = b.sal);
```

Without using TOP, ROWID, rank etc. Works with oldest sql also

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`DBMS_STAT_FUNCS.Summary`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_stat_f.htm#i999450):

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
    s DBMS_STAT_FUNCS.SummaryType;
BEGIN
    DBMS_STAT_FUNCS.SUMMARY('HR', 'EMPLOYEES', 'SALARY',3, s);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Top 3: ' || s.top_5_values(1) || '-' 
                         || s.top_5_values(2) || '-' || s.top_5_values(3));
END;
/
```

Output:

```
Top 3: 24000-17000-17000
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM emp 
ORDER BY Salary desc
FETCH FIRST 3 ROWS ONLY;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT * FROM 
     (
      SELECT EMPLOYEE, LAST_NAME, SALARY,
      DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SALARY DESC) EMPRANK
      FROM emp
     )
    WHERE emprank <= 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select ename, job, sal from emp
    where sal >=(select max(sal) from emp
    where sal < (select max(sal) from emp
    where sal < (select max(sal) from emp)))
    order by sal;

ENAME      JOB              SAL
---------- --------- ----------
KING       PRESIDENT       5000
FORD       ANALYST         3000
SCOTT      ANALYST         3000
```

Answer (score 0):

**Limit The Query To Display Only The Top 3 Highest Paid Employees. : Query « Oracle PL / SQL**

```
create table employee(
         emp_no                 integer         primary key
        ,lastname               varchar2(20)    not null
        ,salary                 number(3)
);

insert into employee(emp_no,lastname,salary)
              values(1,'Tomy',2);

insert into employee(emp_no,lastname,salary)
              values(2,'Jacky',3);

insert into employee(emp_no,lastname,salary)
              values(3,'Joey',4);

insert into employee(emp_no,lastname,salary)
              values(4,'Janey',5);


select lastname,  salary
from (SELECT lastname, salary FROM employee ORDER BY salary DESC)
where rownum <= 3 ;
```

> OUTPUT

```
LASTNAME                 SALARY

-------------------- ----------
Janey                         5

Joey                          4

Jacky                         3

drop table employee;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT salary,first_name||' '||last_name "Name of the employee" 
FROM hr.employees 
WHERE rownum <= 3 
ORDER BY salary desc ;
```

Comment: this will definitely give the names of top 3 salary getting employees and also their salary

Comment: -1 This will not work reliably, see [the manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/pseudocolumns009.htm#i1006297) for an explanation of why `ROWNUM` should not be used this way.

Answer (score -1):

```
    select empno,salary from emp e
     where 3 > ( Select count(salary) from emp
      where e.salary < salary )


Another way :

    select * from
    (
    select empno,salary,
    Rank() over(order by salary desc) as rank from emp )
    where Rank <= 3;

Another Way :

    select * from
    (
    select empno,salary from emp
    order by salary desc
    )
    where rownum <= 3;
```

Comment: please format SQL that you post. Select the code and click the {} button.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM
     (
      SELECT  ename, sal,
      DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SAL DESC) EMPRANK
      FROM emp 
     )
    emp1 WHERE emprank <=5
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT  Name, Salary
FROM 
    (
    SELECT  Name, Salary
    FROM         emp 
    ORDER BY Salary desc
    )
WHERE rownum <= 3
ORDER BY Salary ;
```

Answer (score -1):

select top(3) min(Name),TotalSalary,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by TotalSalary desc) AS RowNumber
 FROM         tbl_EmployeeProfile    group by TotalSalary

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to find any given highest salary
This will give you the 3rd largest salary:

```
select * from emp             
order by sal desc     
limit 2,1;
```

Here, (limit n,m) n represents the start position,
and the m represents how many outputs to display after the start position

If you change the values of n,m you will get the output accordingly.
Eg: (limit 3,1) will give you the 4th largest salary.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(salary) FROM emp order by salary asc limit 0 ,3
```

Above query gives three highest salary with **DISTINCT**.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT * FROM Employees
WHERE rownum <= 3
ORDER BY Salary ;
```

Answer (score -2):

solution for to find top 5 salary in sq l server

select top(1) name, salary from salary where salary in(select distinct top(3) salary from salary order by salary  disc)

Comment: Please try to flesh out your answer a bit more and improve formatting. Also consider if your answer is even relevant in the sense that it contains information which are lacking in the other answers.

Answer (score -3):

```
select top 3 * from emp  order by sal desc
```